# Ansible set_fact with double quotes and back slashes

Tags: ansible, grep, escaping

I'm trying to format a grep command like: `grep -E "\b{{ansible-variable}}(\s|$)"`, but with both double quotes and back slashes, it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest for those cases is to use [YAML multiline syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines).

```yaml
 - command: >-
     grep -E "\b{{ansible_variable}}(\s|$)"
   vars:
     ansible_variable: foo
```

Also, a nice tool to play with its multiple forms can be found [here](https://yaml-multiline.info/).