# Execute command contains double quotes in Ansible

Tags: shell, ansible

I want to execute following command that contains double quotes:

```
- name: Initializing Kubernetes cluster
    shell: kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "hostname:port"
```

Don't know if it will work or not as if I check the command as follows:

```
- debug:
  msg: kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "hostname:port"
```

It gives `kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint \"hostname:port\"`. Why output contains extra backslash between quotes? Will the command execute properly as it is or I have to add something due to double quote? (I couldn't test by executing it as it is a production server)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ansible set\_fact with double quotes and back slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68559796/ansible-set-fact-with-double-quotes-and-back-slashes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: ***"Why output contains extra backslash between quotes?"***

A: Ansible escapes the double quotes in output to tell you the double quotes are part of the string. For example,

```yaml
    - shell: echo "\"This is a double-quoted string.\""
      register: out
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    .           123456789012345678901234567890123
    out.stdout: "This is a double-quoted string."
    length: 33
    out.cmd: echo "\"This is a double-quoted string.\""
```

- It is up to you to include the double quotes. For example,

```yaml
    - shell: echo "This is NOT a double-quoted string."
      register: out
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    out.stdout: This is NOT a double-quoted string.
    out.cmd: echo "This is NOT a double-quoted string."
```

You don't have to escape the double quotes if you use [Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#732-single-quoted-style)

```yaml
    - shell: echo '"This is a double-quoted string."'
      register: out
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    .           123456789012345678901234567890123
    out.stdout: "This is a double-quoted string."
    length: 33
    out.cmd: echo '"This is a double-quoted string."'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - shell: echo "This is NOT a double-quoted string."
      register: out
    - debug:
        msg: |
          out.stdout: {{ out.stdout }}
          out.cmd: {{ out.cmd }}

    - shell: echo "\"This is a double-quoted string.\""
      register: out
    - debug:
        msg: |
          .           123456789012345678901234567890123
          out.stdout: {{ out.stdout }}
          length: {{ out.stdout|length }}
          out.cmd: {{ out.cmd }}

    - shell: echo '"This is a double-quoted string."'
      register: out
    - debug:
        msg: |
          .           123456789012345678901234567890123
          out.stdout: {{ out.stdout }}
          length: {{ out.stdout|length }}
          out.cmd: {{ out.cmd }}
```

---

Q: ***"Do I have to add something due to double-quote (a string)?"***

In the below command, the double quotes will be interpreted by the shell

```yaml
- shell: kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "hostname:port"
```

If you want the double quotes to be part of the string you have either escape it

```yaml
- shell: kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "\"hostname:port\""
```

, or close it in single quotes

```yaml
- shell: kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint '"hostname:port"'
```

Q: ***"Double quotes will be interpreted by the shell. Right?"***

A: Right. The quotes around a script's parameters serve the only purpose to allow whitespaces inside a parameter. For example,

```bash
shell> cat test.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
printf "$1\n"
printf "$2\n"
```

gives

```bash
shell> ./test.sh aaa bbb ccc
aaa
bbb

shell> ./test.sh aa a bbb ccc
aa
a

shell> ./test.sh "aa a" bbb ccc
aa a
bbb

shell> ./test.sh "aa a" "bbb" ccc
aa a
bbb

shell> ./test.sh "aaa" "\"bbb\"" ccc
aaa
"bbb"

shell> ./test.sh "aaa" '"bbb"' ccc
aaa
"bbb"
```

Comment: I wnt execute ```kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "hostname:port"```. As you said "double quotes will be interpreted by the shell", that means ```- shell: kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint "hostname:port"``` will do the same, right?

Comment: Right. I added examples.

Comment: But as you said if "double quotes to be part of the string then I have to use \ or '. It confusing me. If ```"hostname:port"``` interpreted as ```hostname:port``` then answer of  above comment should be "no", as double quotes are part of the command.